# How can I slice x and y coordinates from a Shapely polygon? [TypeError: 'Polygon' object is not iterable]

Tags: python, debugging, shapely

How can I slice `x` and `y` coordinates from a Shapely polygon?

I'm getting the following output:

```
[evaluate xyz_25_2.py]

POLYGON ((3.449182842266765 -5.876385583121159, 2.171707715501299 -3.576930354943315, 0.6387375633827332 -1.447805143667534, -3.875007884521928 6.046715600023223, -6.004133095797705 7.750015769043845, -9.581063450741024 ..........................))

Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "C:\Users\abhi\Desktop\xyz_25_2.py", line 103, in <module>
    list(concave_hull)
TypeError: 'Polygon' object is not iterable
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I edited the title of your question to put the actual question first, and the error message after that. I've also guessed what you meant by 'this' and repeated the question in the question body. I guessed that your previous question body was the output you are seeing, so I've marked it up as a code block without syntax highlighting. Please [edit your question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/35651620/ed) to include the relevant parts of your code that caused that error.

Comment: This question is actually a duplicate of [Extract points/coordinates from a polygon in Shapely](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20474549/7851470)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to retrieve the exterior or interior Linear Ring and feed these into numpy. You can then easily slice the coords.

For example:

```
from shapely import geometry
import numpy as np

# lets create an example polygon
p = geometry.Point(0,0)
poly = p.buffer(100)

# you need to get the coordinates of the exterior (shell)
# pass these into a numpy array
shell_coords = np.array(poly.exterior)
print(shell_coords)

# you can do the same for interior (holes) as well

# then slice and dice to your heart's content
print(shell_coords[:,:1])
print(shell_coords[:,1:2])
```

Comment: these are the points i have calculated for concave hull.. these points come after i perform cascaded_union(edge_points).. i just want to extract points from this object.. when i try i just results to non iterable object

Comment: somewhat ur answer is helpful to me.. although i just want to get x and y values in to different lists... like                                                                          x=[all x values], y=[all y values]

Comment: well.. it worked.. thanks..

Comment: @Abhishekverma when slicing the numpy array you can use ravel().tolist() to convert the contents of the slice to a plain python list. For example `x_list.ravel().tolist()`