# How to get matplotlib.path.Path object from shapely.geometry.Polygon?

Tags: python, matplotlib, shapely

With a list of tuple points I am able to create a `matplotlib.path.Path` object. 
With a point cloud, I have created a `shapely.geometry.Polygon` object by using the `alphashape.alphashape` function.

I would like to convert the `Polygon` object into a `Path` object so that I can utilise `Path.contains_points` which is able to operate on a vector of points instead of `Polygon.contains` which can only operate on a single point.

Consider the following example:

```
import alphashape as aps
import matplotlib.path as mpath
import numpy as np
import shapely.geometry as shgt

points = np.random.rand(100,2)
poly = aps.alphashape(points, 0.2) # 0.2 is a toggle param for best concave hull
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Extract points/coordinates from a polygon in Shapely](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20474549/extract-points-coordinates-from-a-polygon-in-shapely)

Comment: @Georgy thanks for the link. I was wondering whether there was a more direct method