# Most efficient way to find polygon-coordinate intersections in large GeoJSON object

Tags: python, python-3.x, computational-geometry, geopandas, shapely

I'm working on a project that requires coordinate mappings - determining whether a coordinate point exists in a series of polygons. The number of mappings is quite large - ~10 million coordinates across 100+ million polygons.

Before I continue, I've already looked at the questions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20474549/extract-points-coordinates-from-a-polygon-in-shapely) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36399381/whats-the-fastest-way-of-checking-if-a-point-is-inside-a-polygon-in-python). This question isn't redundant since it involves dynamic points and a static polygons.

I've reduced the project's scope for this question by mapping a single coordinate across a subset of 2 million polygons. This is the code I use:

```
from shapely.geometry import shape, Point

f = open('path/to/file.geojson', 'r')
data = json.loads(f.read())

point = Point(42.3847, -71.127411)
for feature in data['features']:
    polygon = shape(feature['geometry'])
    if polygon.contains(point):
        print(polygon)
```

Iterating through 2 million polygons, which in this case are building footprints, takes ~30 seconds (too much time).

I've also tried using `mplPath` as follows:

```
import matplotlib.path as mplPath

building_arrays = [np.array(data['features'][i]['geometry']['coordinates'][0])
                   for i, v in enumerate(tqdm(data['features']))]
bbPath_list = [mplPath.Path(building)
               for building in tqdm(building_arrays)]

for b in tqdm(bbPath_list):
    if b.contains_point((-71.1273842, 42.3847423)):
        print(b)
```

This takes ~6 seconds. An improvement, but still somewhat slow given the volume of mappings I need.

Is there any faster way to achieve such a mapping? I prefer not to use PySpark and distributed computing since I consider that a nuclear option, but I'm open to using that if need be. Is it perhaps possible to vectorize the calculation rather than iterating through the polygons? I'll produce an update showing whether using `numba` made any improvements.

Comment: Definitely try [Paul's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69775644/3888719). Numba will only help if you can use `nopython` mode, which would mean no shapely or matplotlib, so... I would not recommend that. If geopandas.sjoin isn't fast enough, I'd suggest Google BigQuery or another spatial-enabled columnar querying framework - they're ridiculously fast and cheap for this type of thing and I for one have never been able to write anything using a distributed engine like dask approaching the speeds you see there for a spatial query like this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would use a spatial join.

Given this fake data:

[image]

I'd join it with the "within" predicate:

```py
from shapely.geometry import Point, Polygon
import geopandas

polys = geopandas.GeoDataFrame({
    "name": ["foo", "bar"],
    "geometry": [
        Polygon([(5, 5), (5, 13), (13, 13), (13, 5)]),
        Polygon([(10, 10), (10, 15), (15, 15), (15, 10)]),
    ]
})

pnts = geopandas.GeoDataFrame({
    "pnt": ["A", "B", "C"],
    "geometry": [
        Point(3, 3), Point(8, 8), Point(11, 11)
    ]
})

result = geopandas.sjoin(pnts, polys, how='left', op='within')
```

I get:

```
pnt                  geometry  index_right name
  A   POINT (3.00000 3.00000)          NaN  NaN
  B   POINT (8.00000 8.00000)          0.0  foo
  C POINT (11.00000 11.00000)          0.0  foo
  C POINT (11.00000 11.00000)          1.0  bar
```

Comment: works like a charm, thank you! mapped 1 million points to 2 million polygons in 2 seconds

Comment: @mmz that's a really good benchmark to have. Thanks for following up