# Intersection of points and polygons using geopandas

Tags: leaflet, geospatial, intersection, geopandas

I am using the Australian Bureau of Statistics data (ABS) to visualize meshblocks and boundaries  of buffer data from a centre of location with certain radius.

I want to create the following plot:
[intersection plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JKAYA.png)

So far, I am able to create a function which can give me a circle with certain radius depending on the initial coordinates (lon, lat) I have provided.

I have used the following function to plot the circle around the required location on the map:

```
import geopandas as gpd
import pandas as pd
import leaflet
from osgeo import gdal
import shapefile as shp

def func_radius_around_point(point_list,m_list,crs_from,crs_to):

   points_df = pd.DataFrame(point_list).reset_index()
   points_df = points_df.rename(columns={0:'geometry'})
   points_gpd = gpd.GeoDataFrame(points_df,geometry='geometry',crs=crs_from)

for m in m_list:
    buffered= points_gpd.to_crs(epsg=crs_to).buffer(m).to_crs(epsg=crs_from)
    col_name = 'buffered_{m}'.format(m=m)
    points_gpd[col_name] = buffered

return points_gpd
```

I have the data for mesh block and statistical area 1. All I want to create is the intersection of points and polygon. How do I create this intersection using geopandas?

With R, it seems so much easier using the simple features library. Is there a simple features package in geopandas that I have missed out on?

Comment: Check out geopandas.sjoin

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Most efficient way to find polygon-coordinate intersections in large GeoJSON object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69775335/most-efficient-way-to-find-polygon-coordinate-intersections-in-large-geojson-obj)