# Removing the overlapping part between 2 polygons in Python

Tags: python, merge, polygon, shapely, overlapping

I have 2 polygons that have some parts overlapping like this :

[image]

I have the coordinates of the 2 polygons.

I would want to have the coordinates without the overlapping part.

My idea is to create 2 new polygons but without the overlapping part, so reduce the size of one of the polygons.

```
from shapely.geometry import Polygon

p = Polygon([(1,1),(1,2),(4,2),(4,1)])
q = Polygon([(2,1.5),(2,3),(3,3),(3,1.5)])
```

Here is an example of the data that I am working with.

Thanks in advance for the help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is all supported by shapely. Have a look at the [manual](https://shapely.readthedocs.io/en/stable/manual.html) for questions like this.

```
p.symmetric_difference(q)
```

[image]

```
p.difference(q)
```

[image]

```
q.difference(p)
```

[image]

---

To get the coordinates in the case of `symmetric_difference` (https://stackoverflow.com/a/40631091/10020283):

```
from shapely.geometry import mapping

mapping(p.symmetric_difference(q))["coordinates"]
```

Gives multiple lists of coordinates for the different parts of the resulting shape:

```
[(((1.0, 1.0),
   (1.0, 2.0),
   (2.0, 2.0),
   (2.0, 1.5),
   (3.0, 1.5),
   (3.0, 2.0),
   (4.0, 2.0),
   (4.0, 1.0),
   (1.0, 1.0)),),
 (((3.0, 2.0), (2.0, 2.0), (2.0, 3.0), (3.0, 3.0), (3.0, 2.0)),)]
```