# How do I differentiate self-intersection vs. self-touching in shapely?

Tags: python, computational-geometry, shapely

How can I determine if a polygon is self-touching(!) like the blue one, but not self-intersecting like the red one

[image]

Vertices for the two polygons shown in the images is here:

```
from shapely.geometry import Polygon
from shapely.affinity import translate
import pylab

pylab.figure()

points = [[0, 0], [0, 100], [50, 80], [0, 60], [50, 30]]
polygon = Polygon(points)
bounds = polygon.bounds

x,y = polygon.exterior.xy
pylab.plot(x,y, 'b')
pylab.plot(0, 60, 'ko')

points = [[0, 0], [0, 100], [50, 80], [-10, 60], [50, 30]]
polygon = Polygon(points)
polygon = translate(polygon, xoff=70)

x,y = polygon.exterior.xy
pylab.plot(x,y, 'r')

pylab.axis('equal')
pylab.grid(True)
pylab.show()
```

Answer (score 1):

An important remark is that the intersection point on the self touching polygon intersects with polygon segments three times, whereas on the *strictly* self intersecting polygon, intersection points intersect only twice with the polygon segments.

According to this (hopefully, it generalizes well), we can build a method that get intersection points and then checks how many times this point intersects with the polygon segments:

- A strictly self intersecting polygon will only have at least one intersection point that intersects twice with the polygon
- A strictly self touching polygon will have all its intersection points intersecting three times.

To speed up the computation, we can use [SRTree](https://shapely.readthedocs.io/en/latest/manual.html#str-packed-r-tree) (see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14697442/faster-way-of-polygon-intersection-with-shapely)). I also use the polygon to get consecutive segments and points with [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20474549/extract-points-coordinates-from-a-polygon-in-shapely).

```py
from shapely.geometry import Polygon, Point, LineString
from shapely.affinity import translate
from shapely import STRtree


def get_polygon_points(polygon: Polygon) -> list[Point]:
    x, y = polygon.exterior.coords.xy
    return [Point(xx, yy) for xx, yy in zip(x, y)]

def get_polygon_segments(polygon: Polygon) -> list[LineString]:
    points = get_polygon_points(polygon)
    return [
        LineString([[p1.x, p1.y], [p2.x, p2.y]]) for p1, p2 in zip(points[:-1], points[1:])
    ]

def get_intersecting_points(polygon: Polygon) -> list[Point]:
    segments = get_polygon_segments(polygon)
    tree = STRtree(segments)
    intersection_points = set()
    for i, seg in enumerate(segments):
        intersecting_segments_idx = tree.query(seg)
        for idx in intersecting_segments_idx:
            # the condition checks that intersecting segments are not consecutive segments
            if idx != i and idx != (i + 1) % len(segments) and idx != (i - 1) % len(segments):
                intersection = seg.intersection(segments[idx])
                intersection_points.add((intersection.x, intersection.y))

    return [Point(*p) for p in intersection_points]


def self_touching_polygon(polygon: Polygon) -> bool:
    intersection_points = get_intersecting_points(polygon)
    segments = get_polygon_segments(polygon)
    tree = STRtree(segments)

    return all(len(tree.query(p)) == 3 for p in intersection_points)

def strictly_self_intersecting_polygon(polygon: Polygon) -> bool:
    return len(get_intersecting_points(polygon)) > 0 and not self_touching_polygon(polygon)

blue_coords = [[0, 0], [0, 100], [50, 80], [0, 60], [50, 30]]
blue_polygon = Polygon(blue_coords)

red_coords = [[0, 0], [0, 100], [50, 80], [-10, 60], [50, 30]]
red_polygon = Polygon(red_coords)

print(self_touching_polygon(red_polygon), strictly_self_intersecting_polygon(red_polygon))
print(self_touching_polygon(blue_polygon), strictly_self_intersecting_polygon(blue_polygon))
```