Calculate the polygon angle based on point inside?
I have one polygon and want to calculate the wind direction based on the long boundary and point inside. The point is the wind's starting point and the direction follows the long distance to the short edge.
Here's an example of my idea. 1) find the long boundary of polygon 2) find the point of the boundary linestring closest to the starting wind point 3) calculate the wind direction.
Is there any better way to do so?
from shapely import Point, Polygon
from shapely.geometry import LineString
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

coords = ((-1, 0.), (0., 1.), (0.5, 1.), (-0.5, 0.), (-1, 0.))
p = Polygon(coords)

p1 = (0, 0.9)
p2 = (-0.5, 0.2)

fig, axs = plt.subplots()
axs.plot(*p.exterior.xy)
axs.scatter(p1[0], p1[1], c='r')
axs.quiver(p1[0], p1[1], -0.5, -0.5, angles='xy', scale_units='xy', scale=1, color='r')
axs.quiver(p2[0], p2[1], 0.5, 0.5, angles='xy', scale_units='xy', scale=1, color='b')

axs.scatter(p2[0], p2[1], c='b')
axs.set_xlim(-2, 2)
axs.set_ylim(-2, 2)

def calculate_wind_direction(p1, p2):
    dx = p2[0] - p1[0]
    dy = p2[1] - p1[1]
    
    # Calculate the angle in radians
    angle = np.arctan2(dy, dx)
    
    # Convert to degrees
    degrees = np.degrees(angle)
    
    # Adjust to meteorological convention (clockwise from north)
    meteorological_angle = (90 - degrees) % 360
    
    # Convert to "from" direction
    from_direction = (meteorological_angle + 180) % 360
    
    return from_direction

# https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20474549/extract-points-coordinates-from-a-polygon-in-shapely
l = p.boundary # Extract the rectangle boundary as a line
coords = [c for c in l.coords] # List the line coordinates
segments = [LineString([a, b]) for a, b in zip(coords, coords[1:])] # Create the four side lines.
longest_segment = max(segments, key=lambda x: x.length) # Find the longest line (one of the long sides of the rotated rectangle)

p_start, p_end = [c for c in longest_segment.coords] # List the start and end coordinates of it

# set the wind direction from the closest point
if Point(p_start).distance(Point(p1)) < Point(p_end).distance(Point(p1)):
    wdir = calculate_wind_direction(p_start, p_end)
else:
    wdir = calculate_wind_direction(p_end, p_start)



Is the polygon guaranteed to be 4 sided? (if not, how would you like the result to be?)

@VictorSavenije Yes, the polygon should be 4-sided, generated by minimum_rotated_rectangle like this.
